# Gradle: creating a task that extends the compileDebugJavaWithJavac task from and android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to create a task within a plugin that extends the "compileDebugJavaWithJavac" task from the Android plugin for gradle.

This is the code i have within my custom plugin

```
project.task('compileAllJava', type: project.tasks.getByName('compileDebugJavaWithJavac')) << {}
```

When I try to apply this plugin and execute this task it gives me an error like this`A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile_Decorated cannot be cast to java.lang.Class`

Am I extending the task correctly? or is it even possible to extend this task from within my own plugin?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.  The error message is suggesting that `type` needs to be a Class type object, but you've given it a task instead.  Are you actually trying to modify the dependency chain?

Comment: I am just trying to create a task that is an exact copy of the compileDedugJavaWithJavac task

Answer (score 0):

You need to check when the `compileDebugJavaWithJavac` is added to task collection. Try this

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
  if (task.name.equals("compileDebugJavaWithJavac")) {
     project.task('compileAllJava', type: JavaCompile, dependsOn: task) << {
        // your code here
     }
   }
}
```

Check this link to view all task types

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/